# How to get an image onmouseover

Tags: php, image

I am using an image by default But i need the image only when i am doing my mouse over option
This is the div In which Ihave the image

```
<div style="float:left; height:90px; width:90px; background-color:#CCCC99" 
 style="display:block" onmouseover="return mouseOver();" >
 <img src=<?=base_url()?>images/m11on.gif name=b1 width=90
  height=80 border=0 onmouseover=mouseOver() onmouseout=mouseOut()></div>
```

On mouse out my div must be empty
This is the javascript function i am using but it doesnt seems to work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div onmouseover="this.innerhtml='<img src=\"imgurl.jpg\">'" onmouseout="this.innerhtml=''"></div>
```